# Find an index of array item from another json array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexing, find

I am looking to find out an index and group the item belong to in a parent json group, how can I do it?
I am open to reformat the json as well if need be,

I tried JSON.stringify() but it returns the wrong index as well.

```
let Content = {
    group1: [
      [{content:"hello"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello1"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello2"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello3"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello4"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello5"},{content:"world"}],
    ],
    group2: [
      [{content:"hello10"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello11"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello12"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello13"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello14"},{content:"world"}],
      [{content:"hello15"},{content:"world"}],
    ],
  };
//   let currentItem = {type:'group2',index:5};
//   let currentItemContent = Content[currentItem.type][currentItem.index];
let obj = [{content:"hello15"},{content:"world"}];
let newIndex =  Content["group1"].indexOf(obj); 
let type = "group1"; 
if(newIndex < 0)
{
  type="group2"
  console.log(Content["group2"]);
  newIndex = Content["group2"].indexOf(obj); 
}
console.log({"type":type,"index":newIndex});

expected: {type:'group2',index:5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `Content` object using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Check if the given array is in each group by using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Since both the objects in the array seem to be in order, you can simply compare the string returned by `JSON.stringify`

```js
let Content={group1:[[{content:"hello"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello1"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello2"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello3"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello4"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello5"},{content:"world"}]],group2:[[{content:"hello10"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello11"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello12"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello13"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello14"},{content:"world"}],[{content:"hello15"},{content:"world"}]]}

function find(input, search) {
  for (const type in input) {
    const group = input[type];
    const index = group.findIndex(a => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(search));
    
    if (index != -1)
      return { type, index }
  }
  return null
}

console.log(find(Content, [{content:"hello15"},{content:"world"}]))
console.log(find(Content, [{content:"hello"},{content:"world"}]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adiga for prompt answer, JSON.stringify comparison on both was something I kept missing. I have long (one liner) content instead of just "hello" and "world" and its working for that case as well. I just wanted to point that out in case anyone wondering whether it works for long sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Array.find` in combination with `Object.keys` and `Array.some`. The array comparison you can do via `JSON.stringify` however remember that if your keys are in different order that would not work:

```
[{content:"world"},{content:"hello"}] vs [{content:"hello"},{content:"world"}]
```

would not match as you would expect since you are matching on strings and they are now different.

```js
let Content = { group1: [ [{content:"hello"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello1"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello2"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello3"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello4"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello5"},{content:"world"}], ], group2: [ [{content:"hello10"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello11"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello12"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello13"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello14"},{content:"world"}], [{content:"hello15"},{content:"world"}], ], };
      
let findArray = (data, obj) => {
  let index, group = Object.keys(data).find((k,i) => {
    index = i
    return data[k].some(x => JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(obj))
  })
  return { index, group }
}

console.log(findArray(Content, [{content:"hello"},{content:"world"}]))
console.log(findArray(Content, [{content:"hello10"},{content:"world"}]))
```